# what is git-remote-http prcess, why there are so many git processes?

Tags: git, process

i cannot find git-remote-http command in shell, why there is such process?

i only opened one git svn process, why there are so many git related processes?

```
[mirror@home git]$ pgrep git
12035
12036
22308
22309
22394
22397
24128
24129
26136
26137
[mirror@home git]$ pgrep git -lf
12035 git fetch origin
12036 git-remote-http origin http://git.savannah.gnu.org/r/weechat.git/
22308 git svn clone http://code.taobao.org/svn/obconnector/
22309 /usr/bin/perl /home/mirror/ins_git/libexec/git-core/git-svn clone http://xxx.org/svn/xxx/
22394 git update-index -z --index-info
22397 git hash-object -w --stdin-paths --no-filters
24128 git fetch origin
24129 git-remote-http origin http://git.xxx.org/xxx.git/
26136 git fetch origin
26137 git-remote-http origin http://git.xxx.org/xxx.git/
```

Answer (score 2):

It is called a **[remote helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote-helpers)**

> they are invoked by git when it needs to interact with remote repositories git does not support natively.
>   A given helper will implement a subset of the capabilities documented here.
>
> When git needs to interact with a repository using a remote helper, **it 
>   spawns the helper as an independent process**, sends commands to the helper's standard input, and expects results from the helper's standard output.

Note that until Git 2.11 (Q4 2016), a "`git fetch http::/site/path`" (which is an invalid url) would *not* die correctly and would segfault instead.

See [commit d63ed6e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d63ed6ef241b2e7f124089e2672cfce8251ed390) (08 Sep 2016) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c13f458](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c13f458d869fefb603c63ae7bf65fe3d595a8a83), 15 Sep 2016)</sup>

> ### `remote-curl`: handle URLs without protocol
>
> Generally `remote-curl` would never see a URL that did not have "`proto:`" at the beginning, as that is what tells git to run the "`git-remote-proto`" helper (and **`git-remote-http`, etc, are aliases for `git-remote-curl`**).
>
> However, the special syntax "`proto::something`" will run `git-remote-proto` with only "something" as the URL.
>   So a malformed URL like:

```
http::/example.com/repo.git
```

> will feed the URL "`/example.com/repo.git`" to `git-remote-http`.
>   The resulting URL has no protocol, but the code added by 372370f (http: use credential API to handle proxy authentication, 2016-01-26) does not handle this case and segfaults.

---

Git 2.13 (Q2 2017) expand on that by making sure the "smart HTTP" remote
helper understands what to do with the "`--push-options`" passed through the
external remote helper interface.

See [commit 511155d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/511155db51ff9870d2b3fd74c6dfdd558b5fa37b), [commit eb7b974](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eb7b9749f2b7bc0d0e0ac2c68d98cf1b8f4a2761) (22 Mar 2017) by [Brandon Williams (`mbrandonw`)](https://github.com/mbrandonw).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4e87565](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4e87565d2a3e315b7afc39e9e1fe98c5607a1b11), 27 Mar 2017)</sup>

The remote-http process now can receive options, because [git send-pack](https://github.com/git/git/blob/511155db51ff9870d2b3fd74c6dfdd558b5fa37b/Documentation/git-send-pack.txt#L84-L88) has:

```
--push-option=<string>
```

> Pass the specified string as a push option for consumption by     hooks on the server side.  If the server doesn't support push options, error out.

---

Git 2.14 does enforce the push option verification.

See [commit cbaf82c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cbaf82cc6b734244a9190c3341ca5f08f8d5acc4) (09 May 2017), and [commit b7b744f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b7b744f297b736c51636407f5883b3777bb36433) (08 May 2017) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3c98008](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3c980083bc404cb62fb87c76d331c48a44c5f50d), 23 May 2017)</sup>

The receive-pack program now makes sure that the push certificate
records the same set of push options used for pushing.

Answer (score 1):

One separate process for each http request.
There are many clients requesting the service so there are many git processes.